# Correct way to declare an Array member in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class that looks like this

```
class StatisticsQuantiles : public StatisticsMC
{
public:
    StatisticsQuantiles(double p_, unsigned long NumberOfPaths);
    virtual void DumpOneResult(double result);
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const;
    virtual StatisticsMC* clone() const;
private:
    std::vector<double> ResultList;
    double p;
    unsigned long PathsDone;
};
```

Currently it has a vector ResultList which I populate with values in my class when a function is called with a value like so:

```
void StatisticsQuantiles::DumpOneResult(double result)
{
    ResultList.push_back(result);
    PathsDone++;
}
```

Now I know that I will fill this vector with exactly *NumberOfPaths* many values, so I would like to use an array of a fixed size instead. How do I go about getting an array as a member of this class with size *NumberOfPaths*? I'm trying to do something like this which doesn't work of course but you get the idea:

```
class StatisticsQuantiles : public StatisticsMC
{
public:
    StatisticsQuantiles(double p_, const unsigned long NumberOfPaths);
    virtual void DumpOneResult(double result);
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const;
    virtual StatisticsMC* clone() const;
private:
    std::array<double, NumberOfPaths> ResultList;
    double p;
    unsigned long PathsDone;
};
```

Comment: You can't do that; the size of an array must be known at compile time.

Comment: I do know what the size is, I will be initializing the class like so: `double p = 0.05;` `const unsigned long NumberOfPaths = 100000;`  `StatisticsQuantiles absQuantileGatherer(p, NumberOfPaths);` but how do I make it known to my class when I initialize it?

Comment: If you know the size at compile time, you can make it a template, with the size as parameter. Just make sure that the size is a compile-time constant (apply `const` and `constexpr` liverally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the size of std::array must be known at compile time, which is not the case here.
So std::vector is your option I believe.

If you are worried about the efficiency of push_back re-sizing, you can reserve the memory in your constructor.

```
ResultList.reserve(NumberOfPaths);
```

push_back then won't re-size unless you insert more than NumberOfPaths elements. So you don't have the un-necessary resizing.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am doing now but I didn't seem to be getting any improvement in efficiency from reserving the space, which is why I was looking into an array instead.